# WxPython hiding a Horizontal BoxSizer

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, hide, boxsizer

I have a Horizontal boxSizer, inside which I have added 2 images (StaticBitmap).

How do I hide this sizer such that the sizers that are below it come up? Below is the code

```
import wx
import wx.lib
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
import wx.lib.filebrowsebutton

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        #First retrieve the screen size of the device
        screenSize = wx.DisplaySize()
        screenWidth = screenSize[0]
        screenHeight = screenSize[1]
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        # self.SetSize((1200, 650))
        self.SetTitle("Test")
        self.Maximize(True)

        #self.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        #self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 0, 0))

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        # self.nb.SetFocus()
        sizer_1.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)


        self.nbFlash = wx.Panel(self.nb, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.nb.AddPage(self.nbFlash, "Demo")

        sizer_4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        label_10 = wx.StaticText(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, "Images")

        label_10.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, "Arial"))
        sizer_4.Add(label_10, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)

        # sizer_4.Add((10,10), 0, 0, 0)

        sizer_29 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4.Add(sizer_29, 6, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        img1 = wx.Image("Any image path", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        w = img1.GetWidth()
        h = img1.GetHeight()
        w = w*0.5
        h = h*0.5
        img1 = img1.Scale(w,h)
        bitmap_2 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img1))
        sizer_29.Add(bitmap_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        img2 = wx.Image("Any image path", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        w = img2.GetWidth()
        h = img2.GetHeight()
        w = w*0.5
        h = h*0.5
        img2 = img2.Scale(w,h)
        bitmap_3 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img2))
        sizer_29.Add(bitmap_3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)


        sizer_5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4.Add(sizer_5, 3, wx.EXPAND, 0)


        ##Bin File, COM Port
        sizer_5_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_5.Add(sizer_5_1, 1, wx.LEFT, 20)

        label_13 = wx.StaticText(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, "Upload")
        label_13.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, "Arial"))
        sizer_5_1.Add(label_13, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)

        sizer_5_1.Add((0,0), 1, 0, 0)

        self.fbb1 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self.nbFlash, message="Choose an Image")
        sizer_5_1.Add(self.fbb1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 20)

        sizer_5_1.Add((30,30), 1, 0, 0)
        
        label_14 = wx.StaticText(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, "Add")
        label_14.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, "Arial"))
        sizer_5_1.Add(label_14, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)

        sizer_5_1.Add((0,0), 1, 0, 0)

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

    
        sizer_5_1.Add(self.text, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)

        sizer_5_1.Add((0,0), 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)


        self.nbFlash.SetSizer(sizer_4)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)

        self.Layout()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am able to hide the images, but it still keeps the space of the sizers. Now instead of the image, there is blank space.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Sorry don't understand - no images in your code. What is to move to where?

Comment: In the "Any image path" add the path to any image from your system.

The thing is, I want the sizer_29 to be hidden when I click a button, and the sizers that are below it( that contains a button and a text field) to come up. But I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

You can either charge off down the route of getting the children and grandchildren of the widgets in sizer, dealing with them individually, or you can make use of the Sizer's `ShowItems` method.
I've added a Hide button, as your example, inexplicably, was missing the very method you were trying to test.

**Note: example code adjusted for non maximised window**

```
import wx
import wx.lib
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
import wx.lib.filebrowsebutton

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        # self.SetSize((1200, 650))
        self.SetTitle("Test")

        #self.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        #self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 0, 0))

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        # self.nb.SetFocus()
        sizer_1.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)


        self.nbFlash = wx.Panel(self.nb, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.nb.AddPage(self.nbFlash, "Demo")

        sizer_4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        label_10 = wx.StaticText(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, "Images")

        label_10.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, "Arial"))
        self.Hide_images = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Hide Images")
        sizer_4.Add(label_10, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)

        # sizer_4.Add((10,10), 0, 0, 0)

        self.sizer_29 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4.Add(self.sizer_29, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        img1 = wx.Image("frame1.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        w = img1.GetWidth()
        h = img1.GetHeight()
        w = int(w*0.5)
        h = int(h*0.5)
        img1 = img1.Scale(w,h)
        bitmap_2 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img1))
        self.sizer_29.Add(bitmap_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        img2 = wx.Image("frame2.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        w = img2.GetWidth()
        h = img2.GetHeight()
        w = int(w*0.5)
        h = int(h*0.5)
        img2 = img2.Scale(w,h)
        bitmap_3 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(img2))
        self.sizer_29.Add(bitmap_3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)


        sizer_5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4.Add(sizer_5, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)


        ##Bin File, COM Port
        sizer_5_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_5.Add(sizer_5_1, 1, wx.LEFT, 20)

        label_13 = wx.StaticText(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, "Upload")
        label_13.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, "Arial"))
        sizer_5_1.Add(label_13, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)

        sizer_5_1.Add((0,0), 1, 0, 0)

        self.fbb1 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self.nbFlash, message="Choose an Image")
        sizer_5_1.Add(self.fbb1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 20)

        sizer_5_1.Add((30,30), 1, 0, 0)
        
        label_14 = wx.StaticText(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, "Add")
        label_14.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, "Arial"))
        sizer_5_1.Add(label_14, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)

        sizer_5_1.Add((0,0), 1, 0, 0)

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.nbFlash, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

    
        sizer_5_1.Add(self.text, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)

        sizer_5_1.Add((0,0), 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)


        self.nbFlash.SetSizer(sizer_4)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)

        self.Hide_images.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnHide)

        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()
        self.images = True

    def OnHide(self, event):
        if self.images:
            self.images = False
            self.sizer_29.ShowItems(False)
            self.Hide_images.SetLabel("Show Images")
        else:
            self.images = True
            self.sizer_29.ShowItems(True)
            self.Hide_images.SetLabel("Hide Images")
        self.nbFlash.Layout()
        self.nbFlash.Fit()
        
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image][image]

Comment: Hi, it isn't working as expected. On clicking the 'hide' button, the size of the window is reducing...That is not desired. The window should remain maximize only.

Comment: Just the whole sizer_29 should get disappear.
The result should be like the one when you comment sizer_29 (The bottom widgets come up)

Comment: I don't know what platform you're on or if you are maximising the frame, as you do in the example code you submitted. On Linux, the fact that the frame is maximised, means the `Fit` instruction gives exactly what you say you want. The size of the window remains full screen and the items not hidden rearrange themselves. If you are running code that isn't maximised, perhaps you should remove the sizer rather than trying to hide it. It can always be added back.

Comment: I am on windows platform.
The Fit() is perhaps overriding the Maximize()

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your 2nd point.
Remove the sizer and add it back later?
I want there to be a button which hides/shows the images

Comment: 1. Then re-maximise it, after the Fit! 2. The button can't be in the sizer you are hiding or it will be hidden! If that is the case then you need to hide the individual images, which involves taking the child, grandchild approach I mentioned.

Comment: I've adjust the code to handle a non maximised window, by using Fit and Layout on the confusing named notebook panel `nbFlash`